# Error while trying to update brew package manager

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-managers

I tried to update brew:

```
sudo brew update
```

But I got this error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>
> Listing a lot of files
>
> Error: Failed while executing git pull http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git master

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Homebrew recommends not using `sudo`, so you should be able to run `brew update` without it.

Comment: Some OS X El Capitan users will experience this problem for a different reason. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33640543/756329).

Comment: do not use `sudo` for Homebrew

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There was a [bug in Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/cbcd4a32a648d2dfc808066dc3200f92c1a2f020) that was fixed just a few days ago. To fix the bug you can run `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` inside your Homebrew installation. Since that won't fix files that are already seen as modified you can also run `git checkout Library` to replace your checkout with the latest files. (That wipes all edits so take appropriate measures with any you made.)

Comment: I run git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD in /usr/local but I got: fatal: ambiguous argument 'FETCH_HEAD': both revision and filename

Comment: The cause for this is that I once ran brew with sudo.  That created some files with the wrong permissions (owned by root.)  Once I chown'ed the files, then ran that git reset, things were fine.  Thanks!

Comment: I got the same 'fatal', but I don't know what files to chown, how can I discover it?

Comment: @rafa sudo chown -R $(`whoami`) /usr/local

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer is correct but incomplete. If you are getting the error of

**error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:**

Then go to your terminal and run these commands

```
cd /usr/local
```

Then

```
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Then

```
git checkout Library
```

That should get everything in order. Then run

```
brew update
```

Answer (score 15):

Let me add: `cd /usr/local/git`
and then run `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`

Answer (score 11):

go to your terminal and run these commands

```
cd /usr/local

sudo git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD

sudo git checkout Library
```

Answer (score 11):

For those of you using OS X El Capitan, your problem may be System Integrity Protection.

If `/usr/local` exists already, run the following in Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

If `/usr/local` does not exist:

First, try to create `/usr/local` the normal way:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local && sudo chflags norestricted /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

If you see permission issues instead try:

1. Reboot into Recovery mode (Hold Cmd+R on boot) & access the Terminal.
2. In that terminal run: `csrutil disable`
3. Reboot back into OS X
4. Open your Terminal application and execute the line from just above
5. Reboot back into Recovery Mode & access the Terminal again.
6. In that terminal execute: `csrutil enable`
7. Reboot back into OS X & you'll be able to write to /usr/local & install Homebrew.

Answer (score 5):

Out of no reason (or at least no one I'd understand) the repository in `/usr/local` (which is the brew install!) lost its remote repository. So, neither a `git reset` nor a `git pull` and for sure no `brew update` would work.

How do you know that happened? Check `/usr/local/.git/config` whether there are some lines like the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If not do as follows:

```
cd /usr/local
git remote add origin http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git
git pull origin master
```